# Why is snowflake shared object(SO) library over 150MB in size?

Tags: gcc, compilation, odbc, objdump, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to add it on my Heroku instance and it pushes my app build size over the limit.

I'm just confused by the size of this file and ( plz correct me if I'm wrong ), but it seems to have all the debug info in it as well. Here is objdump -h output for reference:

```
$ objdump -h libSnowflake.so

libSnowflake.so:    file format ELF64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      Address          Type
  0               00000000 0000000000000000
  1 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024 00000000000001c8
  2 .gnu.hash     000002c0 00000000000001f0
  3 .dynsym       00002a60 00000000000004b0
  4 .dynstr       000014fa 0000000000002f10
  5 .gnu.version  00000388 000000000000440a
  6 .gnu.version_r 00000120 0000000000004798
  7 .rela.dyn     00219f00 00000000000048b8
  8 .rela.plt     00002088 000000000021e7b8
  9 .init         00000013 0000000000220840 TEXT
 10 .plt          000015c0 0000000000220860 TEXT
 11 .text         00e82e2c 0000000000222000 TEXT
 12 .fini         00000009 00000000010a4e2c TEXT
 13 .rodata       01bdca78 00000000010a4e40 DATA
 14 .eh_frame_hdr 0006b35c 0000000002c818b8 DATA
 15 .eh_frame     00225eec 0000000002cecc18 DATA
 16 .gcc_except_table 000be470 0000000002f12b04 DATA
 17 .tdata        00000004 00000000031d0f78 DATA
 18 .tbss         00000068 00000000031d0f80 BSS
 19 .init_array   00001ac8 00000000031d0f80
 20 .fini_array   00000008 00000000031d2a48
 21 .jcr          00000008 00000000031d2a50 DATA
 22 .data.rel.ro  0010fc28 00000000031d2a60 DATA
 23 .dynamic      00000230 00000000032e2688
 24 .got          00002a48 00000000032e28b8 DATA
 25 .got.plt      00000af0 00000000032e5300 DATA
 26 .data         00007b38 00000000032e5e00 DATA
 27 .bss          000276c0 00000000032ed940 BSS
 28 .comment      000000b2 0000000000000000
 29 .debug_aranges 00049170 0000000000000000
 30 .debug_pubnames 0029bed6 0000000000000000
 31 .debug_info   020ff2e2 0000000000000000
 32 .debug_abbrev 0013c383 0000000000000000
 33 .debug_line   002e78aa 0000000000000000
 34 .debug_str    0073e0ea 0000000000000000
 35 .debug_loc    0204c2e7 0000000000000000
 36 .debug_pubtypes 000e1226 0000000000000000
 37 .debug_ranges 00532100 0000000000000000
 38 .shstrtab     00000197 0000000000000000
 39 .symtab       00271ff8 0000000000000000
 40 .strtab       0080f83f 0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you download the Snowflake ODBC driver from?
I don't see that large of a file in the repo that is referenced in the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-download.html